# How to define a struct for a Swift UI View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a beginner at SwiftUI.

I created a struct to save some text and the detail information link page. like this:

```
struct First: Identifiable {
    let title: String 
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: View //link to customised page
```

the property `link` will save the View I have created as `Page1.swift`, `Page2.swift`, `Page2.swift`...

How to define the link type in the struct First?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don’t think having View as a type of a property is a good idea. What is it that you want to achieve with this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `AnyView`(not recommended):

```
struct First: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: AnyView
```

2. Using generics:

```
struct First<Content: View>: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: Content
```

3. You could instead create an enum:

```
enum First: Int, Identifiable {
    //your cases
    var id: Int {
        return rawValue
    }
    var title: String {
        switch self {
            //cases
        }
    }
    var icon: String {
        switch self {
            //cases
        }
    }
    var link: some View {
        switch self {
            //cases
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar in my code. I use AnyView (not recommended by Apple)

```
struct First: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: AnyView
}
```

and when I call the view, I do

```
AnyView(MyView())
```

OR (thanks Timmy)

```
struct First<Content: View>: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: Content
}
```

and call the view with

```
First(title: "xxx", icon: "xxx", link: View1())
```

The second method does not work if it is included in a static property.

```
Error : Static stored properties not supported in generic types
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use `AnyView`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Comment: how you call the view with generic ?

Comment: Like this: `First(title: "", icon: "", link: View1())`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Timmy, Thanks @dibs,

I use this define and the program run with code
`First(title: "xxx", icon: "xxx", link: AnyView(View1()))`,
`First(title: "xxx", icon: "xxx", link: AnyView(View2()))`,
as below:

```
struct First: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: AnyView
}
```

---

but the second way, there is some wrong when I call views by below way:
`First(title: "xxx", icon: "xxx", link: View1())`,
`First(title: "xxx", icon: "xxx", link: View2())`,

I try to use the way to call view by `link: AnyView(View1())`, `link: AnyView(View2())`, it success.

```
struct First<Content: View>: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let id = UUID()
    let link: Content
```

Thanks the help from @Timmy, @dibs